# how to keep dimensions with alply and mapply

Tags: r, plyr

I have got a three dimensional array *outmv*. I dissolve its third dimension with the help of *alply*, because I want a list of two dimensional matrices, whose numbers of columns will depend on *v* (see *mapply*) and whose number of rows is given by *r*.

I have got two problems:
1. can I keep *alply* from dropping the r-dimension (if r = 1)? (although my workaround with the help of matrix() seems to work)
2. if vend = 5, mapply degenerates my desired output: in case fun(1,5) the result is transposed, in case fun(2,5) the result is even mixed. I really would like to have length(v) matrices, each of having got r rows, for further steps.

```
library(plyr)

fun <- function(r,vend){
 m <- matrix(c(1:20),nrow = r, byrow = TRUE)
 v <- c(5:vend)
 outmv <- outer(m,v) # dim(outmv) = c(dim(m),length(v))

 #outmv_dropped_dim <- alply(outmv,3,function(x) x) 
 #if r = 1, unfortunately, alply drops a dimension automatically,
 #therefore, I cannot use function(x) = x, but 
 outmv_kept_dim <- alply(outmv,3,function(x) matrix(x,nrow = r, 
                                                      ncol = ncol(m)))

 mapply(function(x,y) {x[,c(1:y), drop = FALSE]},
       x = outmv_kept_dim,
       y = v)
}

#11 > vend > 5 works as desired
fun(2,6) #list elements have desired dimension
fun(1,6) #list elements have desired dimension
#v_end = 5 does not work as desired
fun(1,5) #result is transposed
fun(2,5) #result is transposed and mixed and therefore worse
```

Comment: Try changing to `Map` from `mapply`

Comment: Since `Map` is simply just a wrapper around `mapply`, you can also just do `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` to not over-reduce the output. (If you look at the source for `Map`, this is most of what the wrapper does ...

Comment: thanks! SIMPLIFY (capital letters sic) = TRUE does the job

Comment: = FALSE of course, sorry